# svn branch excluding resources directory

Tags: svn, resources, branch, svn-externals

I have trunk and long time (forever) branch and both use the same resources. I mean that the translation of texts in the project are not the subject of branching. I have been merging the resources for long time but I would like to get rid of the manual merging work and keep it sync. I could use svn externals, but I have read that svn externals is suitable for different repositories. Is there another possibility like to set some svn symbolic link back to trunk on this specific resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

> I have read that svn externals is suitable for different repositories

You read (or remember) wrong information: svn:externals works nicely in both cases (and for internal externals SVN has move possibilities, like file-level externals, relative path...)

> I would like to get rid of the manual merging work and keep it sync.

- Externals isn't bad choice, just define it carefully (replacing in branch existing real folder with externalized may have some side effects, AFAICR)
- Without externals, if you change resources **only** in trunk, you can merge subtrees (in Subversion, not by hand) and they will be merged automatically without conflicts and user's intervention... you can (with testing) add this operation even in post-commit hook
- If you change resources **only** in trunk (warning applied again) you can instead of subtree merge just copy folder from trunk to branch after each folder change (testing for `svn copy SRC-URL DST-URL` when DST-URL already exist still needed)